# Will I miss anything by not watching The Matrix Reloaded and The Matrix Revolutions?

Tags: the-matrix, suggested-order, the-matrix-reloaded, the-matrix-revolutions, the-matrix-resurrections

I think I'd like to check out The Matrix Resurrections in the theatre.  I watched the original when it came out in 1999, and the new one seems to have a lot of similar elements to it.

I never watched the 2nd and 3rd movies in the series.  By the time I had heard how much they had been panned, I was happy to have seen the first one only.

If I go to see the new Matrix movie, will I be completely lost having missed characters and story lines from the middle two movies?

Comment: Basically, yes.... There is a lot of plot and characters in the second and third movies that will make a lot of Resurrections incomprehensible without prior viewing

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I don't think I want to do the homework to see the new one.

Comment: @Jason - I've a similar dilemma - it's my partner's *favourite ever* movie series, yet I didn't even like the first one much & fell asleep through the other two. I'm under a lot of peer pressure to rewatch the first three before being compelled to sit through the fourth ;))

Comment: ↑ To give some body to that statement - I absolutely hate visible 'wire work' which was prevalent before CGI was fully developed [& even still visible in Snyder's recent Suicide Squad, when they now ought to know better] so as soon as they started swinging round the pseudo-Japanese 'dojo' like Peter Pan at the local Xmas panto, I lost all interest.

Comment: I guess you have to watch all three.

Comment: @Paulie_D  A follow up question, is it worth it?  Is this latest movie worth watching these other two?

Comment: That's not something anyone can answer for you.

Comment: Well, they *can*.  Just not objectively.

Comment: As an alternative solution or compromise: at least read a detailed synopsis?

Comment: @Flater a good idea.

Comment: This conversation is turning into whether to recommend a movie - might be better done in chat.  FWIW as someone who absolutely loved the first movie, *all* the sequels have been disappointing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.** You will miss a whole lot of things:

- You will miss the whole purpose and rationale behind *Resurrection*.
- You will miss history about recurring characters and what happened to other characters.
- You will miss some key plot elements, like what happened to Zion at the end of *Revolution*.